# React Native - Dynamic URL for UrlTile in MapView

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm using an external map I a MapView in React native using UrlTile like this:

```
    <View style={styles.mapContainer}>
      <MapView
        style={styles.map}
        rotateEnabled={false}
        mapType="none"
        initialRegion={mapRegion}
      >
        <UrlTile urlTemplate={this.tileUrl} style={styles.tiles} />
      </MapView>
    </View>
...

const tileUrl = "https://externalmap.com/3857/{z}/{y}/{x}.png";

const mapRegion = {
  latitude: 61.5309288,
  longitude: 16.7695302,
  latitudeDelta: 16.0,
  longitudeDelta: 16.0
};
```

I wonder if there's a way to have a dynamic URL based on z, y and x values. The reason is that I want to be able to store the tiles locally and then check if the tile exists locally use that, otherwise, use the external URL. Is there any way I could achieve this?

Comment: when you load proper url just change value of tileUrl (and change keyword `const` to `let`)

Comment: The thing is I need to determine the url based on x, y, z values. How do I access the x, y, z values and then do some logic before I resolve the url?